# Numpy ndarray __array_wrap__ not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

The example code given by the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.23/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs-and-other-functions) is giving me a different result.

```
import numpy as np

class MySubClass(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        print('In __array_finalize__:')
        print('   self is %s' % repr(self))
        print('   obj is %s' % repr(obj))
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        print('In __array_wrap__:')
        print('   self is %s' % repr(self))
        print('   arr is %s' % repr(out_arr))
        # then just call the parent
        return super().__array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context)

obj = MySubClass(np.arange(5), info='spam')
arr2 = np.arange(5)+1
ret = np.add(arr2, obj)
```

It was supposed to print the following:

```
In __array_finalize__:
   self is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
   obj is array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In __array_wrap__:
   self is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
   arr is array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
In __array_finalize__:
   self is MySubClass([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
   obj is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

But I'm getting:

```
In __array_finalize__:
   self is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
   obj is array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In __array_finalize__:
   self is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
   obj is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In __array_wrap__:
   self is MySubClass([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
   arr is MySubClass([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

Is it a bug? Is the documentation outdated? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Can you clarify what your code is actually intended to do? I don't understand your expected output.

Comment: @joanis The code is not mine, it's taken directly from the documentation. It's meant to illustrate how to subclass `ndarray` so it works with numpy's universal functions (`ufunc`) and returns the custom subclass instead of `ndarray`. The expected output was also taken directly from the documentation. But when I run the code it gives a different output. It gives the wrong result for `ret` and the special methods `__array_wrap__` and `__array_finalize__` are called in the wrong order.

Comment: Well, if it's any reassurance, you're not going crazy. I reproduced your error and got the same wrong output. If you do `arr2 + obj`, too, the results are wrong. I really don't get it. Is there a way to report numpy bugs?